# Fit to page. Height issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have script which is putting for cameras on the full screen.
I made a script which is create a table:

```
document.getElementById('cameras_content').innerHTML +=
    ('<table height="50%" width="50%" style="float: left;">' + 
        '<tr>' +
            '<td><img id="topImage'+ m +'" width="100%" height="100%"></img></td>' +
        '</tr>' +                                                   
    '</table>');
```

As there is 4 cameras shared on full screen the table is 2x2
I have a problem with make size properly. Horizontally it is okay i have two images which are fit. The problems is vertically. I made a height exactly the same as horizontally but it is not working. Is there any magic command for that ?

Here is the full screen script:

```
function fullscreen(){
var elem = document.getElementById("cameras_content");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use percentages in height in a HTML page, you need to change the way the page sizes itself. (normally, the body resizes itself to accomodate its contents rather than to fill the browser window)

To do this, add the following inside your `<head>` tag :

```
<style type="text/css">
  html{
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    min-height: 100%;
  }

  /* this part is optional, but makes scrollbars etc easier to handle */
  body, html{
     padding:0;
  }
</style>
```

once you have done this, you can use percentage heights on your elements.

Comment: didn't help. still height not fit.. Added my full screen script.

Comment: Requesting full-screen is something completely different from getting an element to fit vertically...